# VB stand alone application or ASP web application

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, web

I have experience developing software and web applications and I have decided to do some freelance work on the side. Well, I met with my first client and they are requesting a relatively simple, custom system that (without being long winded) tracks client’s paperwork as it progresses through the business’s different manual processes. It is a small business that has about 10 employees, but all of the employees will interact with the client’s paperwork, therefore everyone would need access to the new system. When I say ‘track’ I literally mean that the employees will ‘check as complete’ on a simple page the increases a progress bar at different stages for the paperwork. Now I am %110 capable of coding the custom system that meets their needs, but I am unsure about how I should go about doing it.

The information that is being tracked in the new system and stored in the DB is confidential information that they are very protective of. My main question is how should I be developing this to be as secure as I can?

-They have their own server in house, so should I develop an application (VB and SQL) for the server and require employees to log on remotely to use it? Can more than one person access/use the application at a time?

-Or should I develop a web application (ASP.Net/VB and SQL) that is only accessible on their network to their employees? They plan to expand offices, could they set up a VPN to access the site?

I’m leaning towards a web application, but I have not done too much in term of security. Basically I’m looking for pros and cons for either option or any suggestions on what I should.

PS, stackoverflow is awesome! Long time user, first time poster!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about application architecture. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com. 

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop using vb & sql you have to consider that:

- You need to have real ip
- Your system will communicate threw certain port and you have to handle the security measure for letting certain port opened in your server.
- You should have good knowledge in network programming

If you want to develop using asp.net you have to consider that:

- in case only office employees will use the system, you can develop against users in Active Directory and for outside users with username and password with SSL connection or vpn

for preventing more than one person access the file you can simply add column 'locked' in case file is being used.

Comment: Good answer,use ports that might not be obvious and you can test your own system security wise by filtering packets from a certain point in the network and making sure it is not plain text and not easily decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Well im not a web fan (I suck) ive seen too many security issues go with it...i.e Lulzsec, but i do very much love VB apps.

So I would definetely recommend a VB app connected to a MSSQL database (coz it's easy to configure and havent seen any security exploits yet),my Chinese friend told me there is a way to access MySQL free databases.
Now, allow remote access but make sure your Windows Firewall is also configured properly do look at all angles of security.

If I remember well there is an option in MSSQL to specify the IP addresses or is it MAC addresses that can access the DB so maybe input all of the 10 employees' IP addresses assuming they are static,if they are dynamic (DHCP) don't bother. And ask them to make the IP address of the server where you will host the DB on static.
If only 10 employees use the DB then limit the connections to 10.
 For now develop this when it comes to VPN you can make a Remote version of the App im sure that will come later right now focus on the basics.
 Also use Dotfuscator when you are publishing the app I heard it is very good.
N also im suggesting the document/work order is received at the reception so that user will check in the document with specifics...if they are passing on the work order to the next user they should select the user and then THAT user may enter some sort of verification code unique to the user...im sure you can envision the rest from here.
 Now do I also get a cut from this?lol

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the same for years now, and I always take the website side, this days I go width ASP.NET MVC 4, it's easier, **everything in their place and extremely easier to test and maintain**.

The web application has a very **big advantage** to any standalone windows application, you deploy and upgrade only one application instead to maintain all the different versions once you start deploying windows apps, and they are harder to debug once you start to having different machines with different versions and so on...

so, Web or Win app = **Web app**, always!

All you need is a server that run IIS and set it up for using **Active Directory** (Visual Studio has that project already, simply create an ASP.NET MVC and choose the "intranet" template), it will set up everything for you, and all you need later is tweak the Active Directory connection string.

I also use a self-signed **SSL to protect data between client and server**, as I also make the apps available outside the office without VPN needed, as long as they login with their secure AD credentials.

And... **audit everything** into a secondary database, every action performed by a user since they login until they logout, every view, update or creating data witch .NET makes it simple if you create your `Logging` method to simple log messages and Stack messages on errors.

This will greatly benefit your employer and you when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to go with web application. Advantage using web application is, if they want to expand bussiness .. same can you do with you WebApp. But choose .Net over VB, going with latest techonology will help you resolve current challanges.